# Python vkapi 142 ERROR: Permissions obtained

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, vkontakte-api, python-3.5

Сервер на Python 3.5, стоящий на Ubuntu, внезапно начал выдавать вот такую ошибку:

```
2018-02-08 18:43:09,848 vk    mixins:127 INFO: Getting permissions
2018-02-08 18:43:09,849 vk    mixins:142 ERROR: Permissions obtained
Process Process-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/process.py", line 249, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/antispam/main.py", line 49, in fpost
    session = vk.AuthSession(config['general']['appid'], config['general']['login'], config['general']['pass'], scope='wall, groups')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/vk/mixins.py", line 32, in __init__
    self.access_token = self.get_access_token()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/vk/mixins.py", line 70, in get_access_token
    auth_response_url_query = self.oauth2_authorization()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/vk/mixins.py", line 143, in oauth2_authorization
    raise VkAuthError(error_message)
vk.exceptions.VkAuthError: VK error: [invalid_request] Security Error
```

Сам код сервера выглядит примерно так:

```
import sys
from multiprocessing import Process
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import ssl
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import json
import configparser
import vk

# function that filters a  comment
def f(gid, pid, cid, uid, text):
    print('Comment from '+gid+' validation in process...')
    session = vk.AuthSession(config['general']['appid'], config['general']['login'], config['general']['pass'], scope='wall, groups')
    vk_api = vk.API(session)
    if text=="":
        print('Empty comment, killing.')
        if vk_api.wall.deleteComment(owner_id="-"+gid, comment_id=cid)==1:
            print('Killed it!')
        else:
            print('Error: can not kill!')
        print('Comment validation complete.')
        return;
    if vk_api.groups.isMember(group_id=gid, user_id=uid)!=1:
        print('Invalid user, killing.')
        if vk_api.wall.deleteComment(owner_id="-"+gid, comment_id=cid)==1:
            print('Killed it!')
        else:
            print('Error: can not kill!')
        print('Comment validation complete.')
        return;
    print('User is valid, checking banned words...')
    low = text.lower()
    with open("/antispam/banned.txt") as f:
        content = f.readlines()
    banned = [x.strip() for x in content] 
    for word in banned:
        if word in low:
            print('Found banned word, killing.')
            if vk_api.wall.deleteComment(owner_id="-"+gid, comment_id=cid)==1:
                print('Killed it!')
            else:
                print('Error: can not kill!')
            break
    print('Comment validation complete.')

# function that filters a post
def fpost(gid, pid, uid, text):
    print('Post '+pid+' from '+gid+' validation in process...')
    session = vk.AuthSession(config['general']['appid'], config['general']['login'], config['general']['pass'], scope='wall, groups')
    vk_api = vk.API(session)
    if text=="":
        print('Empty post, killing.')
        if vk_api.wall.delete(owner_id="-"+gid, post_id=pid)==1:
            print('Killed it!')
        else:
            print('Error: can not kill!')
        print('Post validation complete.')
        return;
    if vk_api.groups.isMember(group_id=gid, user_id=uid)!=1:
        print('Invalid user, killing.')
        if vk_api.wall.delete(owner_id="-"+gid, post_id=pid)==1:
            print('Killed it!')
        else:
            print('Error: can not kill!')
        print('Post validation complete.')
        return;
    print('User is valid, checking banned words...')
    low = text.lower()
    with open("/antispam/banned.txt") as f:
        content = f.readlines()
    banned = [x.strip() for x in content] 
    for word in banned:
        if word in low:
            print('Found banned word, killing.')
            if vk_api.wall.delete(owner_id="-"+gid, post_id=pid)==1:
                print('Killed it!')
            else:
                print('Error: can not kill!')
            break
    print('Post validation complete.')


# launcher that triggers a function
class S(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def _set_headers(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
        self.end_headers()
        print('Its me, a request!')

    def do_GET(self):
        self._set_headers()
        self.wfile.write(b'ok')
        print('Got a GET!')

    def do_HEAD(self):
        self._set_headers()

    def do_POST(self):
        global config
        self._set_headers()
        varLen = int(self.headers['Content-Length'])
        postVars = self.rfile.read(varLen)
        data = json.loads(postVars.decode('utf-8'))
        groupid = str(data['group_id'])
        if data['type']=="confirmation":
            self.wfile.write(bytes(config[groupid]['confirmationcode'], 'utf-8'))
        else:
            #launching process...
            if data['type']=="wall_reply_new":
                try:
                    st = data['object']['text']
                except NameError:
                    st = ""
                p = Process(target=f, args=(groupid,str(data['object']['post_id']),
                                            str(data['object']['id']),
                                            str(data['object']['from_id']),
                                            st
                                            ))
                p.start()
                p.join()
                self.wfile.write(b'ok')
            elif data['type']=="wall_post_new":
                try:
                    st = data['object']['text']
                except NameError:
                    st = ""
                p = Process(target=fpost, args=(groupid,
                                            str(data['object']['id']),
                                            str(data['object']['from_id']),
                                            st
                                            ))
                p.start()
                p.join()
                self.wfile.write(b'ok')
            else:
                self.wfile.write(b'Error: aztan praaaativnyj')
        print('Got a POST!')
# launcher that launches previous launcher
def run(server_class=HTTPServer, handler_class=S, port=443):
    server_address = ('', port)
    httpd = server_class(server_address, handler_class)
    print ('Starting httpd...')
    # SSL LAUNCH
    httpd.socket = ssl.wrap_socket (httpd.socket, server_side=True, certfile='/root/antispam-system_ru.crt', keyfile='/root/key.txt', cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_OPTIONAL, ca_certs='/root/antispam-system_ru.ca-bundle')
    httpd.serve_forever()

# main part
if __name__ == "__main__":
    global config
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.sections()
    config.read('/antispam/pass.ini')
    run()
```

Никак не могу понять, в чем дело - глобальные переменные в процесс передаются нормально.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно логин и пароль на аккаунте устарели? ну например заморозили его. Из ошибки видно что авторизация перестала проходить.

А так же попробуйте авторизацию без указания app_id, если проблема будет решена, попробуйте app_id другого приложения.

Comment: Да, я использовал новый app_id и обнаружил, что старый заблокировали. Большое спасибо!